# Не получается объявить явную специализацию шаблона функции

Tags: c++, функции, visual-c++, шаблоны-с++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
template <typename T>
T maxn(const T[], int);
template <> const char * maxn(const char[], int);

int main() {
    int arr1[]{ 3, 321, -41, 421, 4, 0 };
    double arr2[]{ 42.42, -421.005, 0, 123.555 };
    const char *arr3[]{ "ewqeeq", "321", "ew", "qwe", " " };
    cout << maxn(arr1, 6) << endl;
    cout << maxn(arr2, 4) << endl;
    cout << maxn(arr2, 5) << endl;
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}

template <typename T>
T maxn(const T arr[], int n) {
    T thebiggest = *arr;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        if (*(arr + i) > thebiggest) {
            thebiggest = *(arr + i);
        }
    }
    return thebiggest;
}
template <> const char * maxn(const char arr[], int) {
    int long1 = strlen(*arr);
    const char * thelongest;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (strlen(*(arr + i) > long1) {
            long1 = strlen(*(arr + i);
            thelongest = (arr + i)
        }
    }
    return thelongest;
}
введите сюда код
```

В общем, задание таково: функция должна получать массив чисел и его длину и возвращать наибольшее, если функция получает массив указателей на char, она должна вернуть указатель на самую длинную строку. С первой частью задания я справился, однако, вторая мне никак не даётся.  
MS VS просто не даёт мне объявить явную специализацию шаблона для случая передачи функции ссылки на массив указателей, пишет:

> явная специализация; "const char *maxn(const char [],int)" не является
>   специализацией функции-шаблона

.  
(И ещё один подвопрос: почему я не могу объявить массив указателей на char не константным?)   
P.S. в задании указано, что я должен использовать именно специализацию, а не перегрузку функции.

Comment: Опечатались. Сами же сказали, нужен массив указателей на `char`. Не `const char[]`, а `const char *[]`. (Еще, не "спецификация", а "специализация".)

Comment: *"почему я не могу объявить массив указателей на char не константным"* Он не сам константный, а указатели в нем на константы. Потому что инициализируете его строковыми литералами, то есть `const char []`ами. Компилятор не дает просто так снять `const`, чтобы вы случайно что-то не поменяли.

Comment: cпасибо за второй комментарий. А насчет первого, то я хочу передавать функции указатель на массив указателей. Ах да, я тогда должен буду, как я понимаю, применить двойное разыменование, чтобы извлечь сам строковой литерал, когда нахожу его длину, уже вижу ошибку в коде. Но проблема в том, что мне MS VS не даёт даже просто создать эту специализацию функции, даже пустую. Просто пишет "явная специализация; "const char *maxn(const char [],int)" не является специализацией функции-шаблона" Почему не является? Мне непонятно

Comment: Не сочтите за оскорбление, но вы явно плаваете в плюсах, я бы даже сказал тонете. Вы уверены, что вам нужно изучать С++ именно с такой сложной темы, как шаблоны? Дальше будет только сложнее.

Comment: Хах, не знаю, вроде планомерно двигался по книге. Вот вторая глава, посвященная функциям, и в ней рассказано о шаблонах для функций. А в заданиях после, собственно, это. Я же не сразу начал их изучать, я к ним, вроде как, планомерно шел...

Comment: Ну раз по книге, вопросов больше не имею, извиняюсь за небольшой оффтоп :)

Comment: Вообще, я все задания до сего периода (шаблонов) делал сам. Но с ними что-то слишком неясное, даже перечитывал - не помогло. Пришлось аккаунт на этом сайте завести )

Comment: Хорошо, даже следуя вашему совету, MS VS не даёт мне создать такую специализацию 
     'template <> const char * maxn (const char *[], int)'

Comment: параметр шаблона это вторые <> после имени функции?

Comment: Пардон, недоглядел. Там же `const` изначально стоял, нужно `const char *const []`.

Comment: @bipll Не, он должен определяться сам если не указан. Мы `const` забыли.

Comment: Cпасибо. Как отметить комментарий как решение? =)

Comment: Никак. :) Можно запостить свой ответ, написать это туда, а потом отметить ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для какого конкретного значения шаблонного параметра `T` вы пытаетесь объявить специализацию?

Например, если бы вы захотели объявить специализацию для `T == char`, то после подстановки специализация бы приняла вид

```
template <> char maxn(const char[], int);
```

Но я не вижу никакого значения типа `T` для которого специализация вашего шаблона могла бы принять вид

```
template <> const char * maxn(const char[], int);
```

Об этом вам и говорит компилятор.

Answer (score 0):

Там же `const` изначально стоял, нужно `const char *const []`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
template <typename T>
T maxn(const T[], int);
template <> const char * maxn (const char *const[], int);

int main() {
    int arr1[]{ 3, 321, -41, 421, 4, 0 };
    double arr2[]{ 42.42, -421.005, 0, 123.555 };
    const char *arr3[]{ "ewqeeq", "321", "ew", "qwe", " " };
    cout << maxn(arr1, 6) << endl;
    cout << maxn(arr2, 4) << endl;
    cout << maxn(arr3, 5) << endl;
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}

template <typename T>
T maxn(const T arr[], int n) {
    T thebiggest = *arr;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        if (*(arr + i) > thebiggest) {
            thebiggest = *(arr + i);
        }
    }
    return thebiggest;
}

template <> const char * maxn(const char * const arr[], int n) {
    unsigned int long1 = strlen(arr[0]);
    const char * thelongest = arr[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (strlen(arr[i]) > long1) {
            long1 = strlen(arr[i]);
            thelongest = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return thelongest;
}
```

Вот окончательный вариант решения задачи, если кому-то будет интересно.
Книга "Язык программирования C++" С. Прата. 6-е издание. Глава 8, задание 6.

Comment: Нет. `const` тут сбоку припеку. Основное исправление, которое вы сделали не имеет никакого отношения к `const`. Основное исправление - это именно появление `*` в объявлении параметра функции.

Comment: @AnT если убрать второе объявление const, код не скомпилируется

Comment: Разумеется. Но речь идет о том, что в вашем исходном варианте вообще некуда ставить "второе const". Там не может быть никакого "второго const" из-за того, что не хватает `*`. Это и есть основная ошибка.